# javascript code is not being executed

Tags: php, javascript

I am working on this project in which I am trying to get a returned value so I can autofill my input boxes according to what the client selects.

This code however is not executing and I do not know why. When I remove the `src="jquery area"` `$(#dropdown).on` is an undefined method; not to sure what to do.

```
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
//$.post(url, [data], [callback], [callback type])

    ("#dropdown").on('change', function() {//when you select something from the dropdown function run and will switch the data
        $.post("backgroundScript.php", {
                uid: $(this).val()
            },
             function(data) {
                 $("#first").val(data.first);
               $("#last").val(data.last);
               // etc.;
            }, 'json'
        );

    });
</script>
```

Here's my full code

```
try {  
  # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL  
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
  $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

  //$DBH->prepare('SELECT first FROM contacts');
}  
catch(PDOException $e) { 
    echo "I'm sorry, I'm afraid I can't do that.";  
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);   
}  
//get query
$FNresult=$DBH->query('SELECT first FROM contacts'); 
//set fetch mode
$FNresult->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$dropdown = "<select name='contacts' id='contacts' >";

while($row =$FNresult->fetch()) {

  $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['first']}'>{$row['first']}</option>";
 // echo getLN();

}

$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";

echo $dropdown;

//}
/*
//                  Get last name

function getLN(){
    $query = "SELECT last FROM contacts";
    $LNresult=mysql_query($query);

    $last;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($LNresult)) {

        $last = "{$row['last']}";

    }
    echo $last;
}//end getLN
*/

$DBH = null; 
?>
<!-- javascript on client-side -->
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
//$.post(url, [data], [callback], [callback type])

    ("#dropdown").on('change', function() {//when you select something from the dropdown function run and will switch the data
        $.post("backgroundScript.php", {
                uid: $(this).val()
            },
             function(data) {
                 $("#first").val(data.first);
               $("#last").val(data.last);
               // etc.;
            }, 'json'
        );

    });
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">

/*("#dropdown").on('connection', function (stream) {
  console.log('Ah, we have our first user!');
});*/</script>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" id="first" name="first"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" id="last"><br>
Phone: <input type="text" id="phone"><br>
Mobile: <input type="text" id="mobile"><br>
Fax: <input type="text" id="fax"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" id="email"><br>
Web: <input type="text" id="web"><br>
<input type="Submit">
</form>
```

here is my new edited script on output page =

```
<script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>    

//$("#dropdown-parent").on('change','#dropdown', function() { // replace dropdown-parent
    $("#contacts").on('change','#dropdown', function() {

        $.post("backgroundScript.php", { 
                uid: $(this).val() 
            }, 
             function(data) { 
                 $("#first").val(data.first); 
                 $("#last").val(data.last); 
                 // etc.; 
            }, 'json' 
        ); 
    }); 
</script>
```

here is the php file for backgroundScript.php =

```
<?

// background script

// retrieve data based on $_POST variable, set to $returnArray

$returnArray = $_POST[array(
         'first' => firstName,
         'last' => lastName,
)];

/****************************
 * the structure of returnArray should look something like
     array(
         'first' => firstName,
         'last' => lastName,

     )*/
echo json_encode($returnArray);
?>
```

this file will send in info so the javascript will then replace form fields with what ever is held in the areas appointed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include your jQuery prior to using it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // Your Code Here
</script>
```

Better yet would be to use external JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/site.js"></script>
```

And if you're using HTML5 the `type="text/javascript"` isn't even needed so:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/site.js"></script>
```

Even better still would be to use a jQuery [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/site.js"></script>
```

Also, as others have noted, be sure to use `$` at the beginning of your jQuery factories. i.e. `$('#dropdown')`

-- Update --

Further clarification on project tree, most basic project trees look like this:

```
root/
 |--css/
 |--images/
 |--js/
    |--site.js
 |--index.html
```

-- Update 2 --

Example of a `$.post`

```
$.post({
    'somescript.php', // Script your posting to
    { 
        someParam1: someData1, // $_POST['someParam1']
        someParam2: someData2
        // etc etc
    },
    function(response){
        // Do something with JSON response upon successful post
        alert(response);
    },
    'json' // Tells the script that JSON will be returned
});
```

-- Update 3 --

Okay so basically you want to do is...

Javascript:

```
var dropdown = $('#dropdown');

dropdown.bind('change', function(){
    $post.(
        'backgroundScript.php', 
        { 
            first: dropdown.val() 
        },
        function(response) {
            $('#first').val(response.first);
            $('#last').val(response.last);
            // Repeat for all of your form fields
        },
        'json'
    );
});
```

Receive POST param:

```
$firstName = $_POST['first'];
```

MySQL query would be something like the following:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT *
    FROM contacts
    WHERE first = :first');
$sth->bindParam(':first', $first, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

Then add all of your MySQL fields into associative array array(key => value) and then `json_encode` and return array.

Comment: You would create a directory/folder in your project tree called "js" and then inside that create a file called "site.js". Then you would put your custom script without the `<script></script>` tags inside. This essentially would result in the same thing, but using best practices.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a basic project tree example to go along with my suggestion about external JS.

Comment: function(data) { 
                 $("#first").val(data.first);  this i get a null error about first

Comment: Can you post an example of the JSON your PHP script is returning? I'll need it to help you troubleshoot further.

Comment: Okay so it does not appear your PHP script is doing anything with the data you are sending it which is the `uid`. I'm going to update my post with a clean example of `$.post`, but can you explain what you're trying to pass in?

Comment: do you have a gmail account so we could chat? it be easier and faster?

Comment: what do i need to do for the part after the url script

Comment: I guess I don't get why your posting data just to have it returned back? You could just bind a change event to the form fields and then on the callback for that event update the values. Do you need to post the data to the script for a reason, is it do other things like storing or retreiving data from a DB, etc?

Comment: okay so this is what i am trying to create.  I am trying to create a here....go to http://pcgprotects.com/PCG/test.php and i want to when you click a value in the dropdown menu to fill in the blank forms with a value stored on the db  the drop menu is populated with the first row of names...i want to autofil the blanks when selecting a name

Comment: with what is stored for that name so name = last + phone+ zip + etc.....so those values will fill in the blanks acording to the data stored

Comment: Okay so then you need to change your script to listen for $POST['uid'] and then you would have to query your DB for the uid (I'm assuming this is the key index) in the table you are storing the data in. Then format the result of that query into a JSON object for return via the callback function.

Comment: i dont nessasairy know how to do that could you help me?

Comment: Hehe, well I'd be happy to in a short answer, the problem is it requires a lot of information about your DB setup, such as the setup of your database, i.e. tables and fields, type of database (e.g. MySQL, Postgresql, etc) how your connecting to your DB, etc.

Comment: so i have a table then the rows the drop down menu is produced by the the first field of each row which is name and that loops and gets all names field and creates a drop down menu of them so i want for each name displayed in the dropdown menu to have its own value that will autofill the blanks if there is any info. i am just using one table called contacts. connecting through pdo

Comment: and do you have a gmail account we could chat?

Comment: Sorry, just reread your post and saw you already posted your query and PDO statement. I do have Gmail, but don't like to post it on public boards, too many eyeballs ;).

Comment: Go ahead and remove it. I updated my answer to include an example of how to accomplish what you want to do. Just keep in mind that you need  to make sure that the keys you set in your associative array need to match what you call on the response JSON object. So if your array has an entry like hte following: `'test' => 'This is only a test'` you would access that on the JS side as `response.test`. P.S. if my answer has been helpful please upvote/accept. ;)

Comment: so where the the stuff do after the script you posted, in the backgroundScript or same place?

Comment: where does the bottom 2 things go?

Comment: First part in your <script> blocks or inside your site.js if you elected to go with my external JS suggestion. Last two parts in your PHP script.

Comment: php script - you mean the backgroundScript.php? and what do you mean by - Then add all of your MySQL fields into associative array array(key => value) and then json_encode and return array.

Comment: I just want to clarify something. The examples I posted weren't the only code you would need. I just posted the bits that were the main function aspects to give you an idea on how to proceed. Post an updated copy of your HTML file, JS file and PHP file so I can have a look where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that your PHP script is returning some formatted html, which you then try to insert into the dom via .val(). That method is used to set the values of form fields, not insert entire chunks of html. Try using `.append()` or `.html()` instead, plus do what Phil suggested above - split your script into multiple blocks.

Comment: marc what do you mean using the .append() method.. could you give me some code?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>    
    $("#dropdown-parent").on('change','#dropdown', function() { // replace dropdown-parent
        $.post("backgroundScript.php", { 
                uid: $(this).val() 
            }, 
             function(data) { 
                 $("#first").val(data.first); 
                 $("#last").val(data.last); 
                 // etc.; 
            }, 'json' 
        ); 

    }); 
<script>
```

In your PHP you should have something like this

```
echo json_encode(array('first' => $some_value, 'last' => "Other value"));
```

Comment: i have it in backgroundScript.php it gets the val

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
("#dropdown").on('change', function() {
```

be

```
$("#contacts").on('change', function() {
```